# Удалить из файла строки которые содержат unicode симфолы bash

Tags: linux, bash

У меня есть большой файл (около 30 гб), мне нужно из него вырезать все строки, которые содержат, что либо кроме a-zA-Z0-9 и всех спецсимволов (!@#$%^&*() ... и т.д.).

Comment: У вас что за тип файла?

Comment: Вопрос не определен до конца. Уточните: все строки содержащие ТОЛЬКО юникод, все строки содержащие ХОТЯ БЫ один юникод символ. желательно предоставить формат. Проверка на UTF-8 `iconv -f UTF-8 your_file > /dev/null; echo $?`

Comment: Так-то a-zA-Z0-9 и спецсимволы это тоже очень даже unicode-символы

Comment: @andreymal да уже этот вопрос поднял в обсуждениях. Думаю с данной формулировкой вопрос решений может быть очень много и все НЕ удовлетворять поставленного вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
~$ grep -Pv "^[a-zA-Z0-9!@\#\$%\^\&\*\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]*$" big_file
```

добавте в группу что пропущенно

-v игнорировать строки содержащие патерн

После небольших изысканий:

> UCS characters U+0000 to U+007F (ASCII) are encoded simply as bytes
>   0x00 to 0x7F (ASCII compatibility). This means that files and strings
>   which contain only 7-bit ASCII characters have the same encoding under
>   both ASCII and UTF-8.

у `grep` есть функция чтения бинарных файлов как текст. Получается нужно исключить значения от b\x00 до b\x7F

```
 ~$ grep -Pav '^[b\x00-b\x7F]*$' big_file
```

---

Да интересный вопрос вышел, в лесу разнообразных кодировок для печатных символов можно заблудится.

Рабочий вариант на основе ключевой статьи [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139737). Просуммировав все выше перечисленное, нужно найти шестнадцатеричные последовательности удовлетворяющие условие `[\x00-\x7D]` но вывести все символы за пределами этого промежутка.

Конечно если речь идет о чем то подобном UNICODE/UTF-8/ASCII, а не "сыром" бинарном файле.

```
~$ cat test-3
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}|
АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя

~$ hexdump -C test-3
00000000  21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28  29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30  |!"#$%&'()*+,-./0|
00000010  31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38  39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 40  |123456789:;<=>?@|
00000020  41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48  49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50  |ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP|
00000030  51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58  59 5a 5b 5c 5d 40 61 62  |QRSTUVWXYZ[\]@ab|
00000040  63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a  6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72  |cdefghijklmnopqr|
00000050  73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a  7b 7c 7d 7c 0a d0 90 d0  |stuvwxyz{|}|....|
00000060  b0 d0 91 d0 b1 d0 92 d0  b2 d0 93 d0 b3 d0 94 d0  |................|
00000070  b4 d0 95 d0 b5 d0 81 d1  91 d0 96 d0 b6 d0 97 d0  |................|
00000080  b7 d0 98 d0 b8 d0 99 d0  b9 d0 9a d0 ba d0 9b d0  |................|
00000090  bb d0 9c d0 bc d0 9d d0  bd d0 9e d0 be d0 9f d0  |................|
000000a0  bf d0 a0 d1 80 d0 a1 d1  81 d0 a2 d1 82 d0 a3 d1  |................|
000000b0  83 d0 a4 d1 84 d0 a5 d1  85 d0 a6 d1 86 d0 a7 d1  |................|
000000c0  87 d0 a8 d1 88 d0 a9 d1  89 d0 aa d1 8a d0 ab d1  |................|
000000d0  8b d0 ac d1 8c d0 ad d1  8d d0 ae d1 8e d0 af d1  |................|
000000e0  8f 0a                                             |..|
000000e2

~$ LC_CTYPE=C grep -Pv "[\x00-\x7D]" test-3
АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя
```

> Т.к. вопрос не определен до конца, добавил свой критерий: вывести
>   любую строку НЕ содержащую символ со значением от x00  до x7D.

**Ссылки**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752913
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19491
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139737

Спецификация ASCII и UNICODE

- https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Не работает. Здесь можно как-нибудь передать файл?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev через GitHub можно поделиться снипетом.

Comment: не держим-с. Ну ладно, это можно и на словах. Возьмите строки с č, ć, š и т.п. (я тестировал их ещё и с неправильной кодировкой, то есть системная локаль UTF8, а в файле CP1250) — ваш RE их пропускает.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev пишите с тегом ника.  да читаю подробней по юникод на юниксах.

Comment: иронично, что за несколько часов каждый из нас с вами пришёл к первоначальной идее другого :)
Движок съедает ваш ник при размещении комментария.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev основы то одни) back-to-basics как говорится. Это сдвиг сознания наверно понимать, что машины не понимают текст вообще...

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо за вопрос, неожиданно трудный при кажущейся простоте.

Я не смог решить его при помощи `grep`, но простой скрипт на перле делает то что нужно:

-- myfilter.pl --

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    if ($_ !~ m/[^\w\s\/^.@#$%&*(){}\[\],:;?!<>-]/) {
      print "$_";
    }
}
```

Использование: `cat big_file.txt |perl myfilter.pl >filtered_file.txt`
Пустые строки сохраняются!

Comment: Размышлял о Python3, там по умолчанию все строки - юникод. Шаблон прелставленный автором - тоже может быть юникод. Все будет зависить от формата сохраненного файла.

Comment: Установлен тэг "linux". В UTF-8 описанное автором множество однобайтовое и полностью совпадает с ASCII. Так что вряд ли, если только мы говорим о текстовом файле (это из вопроса не очевидно, согласен).

Comment: Символы вида ㄀ пропускаются! Может от обратного все таки ? Требуется оставить только строки состоящие из a-zA-Z0-9(и спец символ) . Не факт, что все эти маски будут одновременно, например, lol8798 (a-z0-9) нам подходит и мы оставляем эту строку. Но строку yuUBJH^87㄀㄀㄀㄀$ мы убираем ибо есть левый символ ㄀

Comment: идея @Hellseher по своей сути правильнее. Понять бы, почему она не работает в нынешнем виде... Кстати, проверил у себя вашу строчку (с символом 0x84e3) — у меня удаляется. Чудеса...

Comment: Поправил, вроде работает (проверил и на kanji). Изменил в ответе, проверьте.